# Search for files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

How do i search for files in Sublime Text 2 inside a project?

I don't want to search the contents of files, just file names.

This should be ridiculously simple but I can't figure out (Google points some answers to the [Sublime Text Forum](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum) but it is offline right now)

A keyboard shortcut would be amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Ctrl+P (or Cmd+P) to open Goto Anything and just start typing the filename you're looking for!

[source](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html)